# How to inherit class into HTML project

Tags: html, class, inheritance, bootstrap-4

I want to write a simple one-page HTML page with Bootstrap.
I need to write a method using a 3rd party library for a certain task.
Is it possible to create a class in a HTML project than inherits that class into a HTML page and connects it to a button?

**I am currently doing that on ASP but I want to use HTML.**

Comment: You have to explain better. Html doesn't have classes, and css classes don't have inheritance.

Comment: No i ment like in the asp. Whic has aspx and aspcs files. You write your methods in cs and view it on x. I want a structure like that on html l, is it possible? Like controller and view in mvc but in html. Perhaps using node.js? I dont know what to use and where to begin.

Comment: Is that third party library client side or server side? I still don't understand what you mean by "inherit". If I understand well, a click on the button should call that method. And how do you render the html? Is it just static and handcoded or is it generated by a script?

Comment: its a server side library. Lets just say it gathers some numbers from another website and collect the specified info to a list. than prints the result onto html as excel format.